# How can I count all the children of a parent node that have a certain class with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In javascript preferably. For example:

```
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="one"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
      <div class="two"></div>
    </div>
```

how would I count the number of child elements with class "one" (3)? Thank you.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("#parent > .one").length`

Comment: Thank you, and how would I do it if the parent is a class and there is another parent class later in the html. Sorry I'm new at this.

Comment: If you have the parent element in a variable `p`, it's `p.querySelectorAll("> .one").length`

Comment: What do you mean by "later in the html"? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Barmar: That only works in jQuery.

Comment: The "querySelectorAll" is not a jQuery method. See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: If "parent" is a class instead of an element ID, the selector changes to this: ".parent > .one"), and this will select ALL elements with class "one" that are sub-elements of an element with the  "parent" class. If you want to be specific about which elements are counted, you will have to be more particular about which classes are involved, and what your selector is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors.
>
> ---
>
> selectors is a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.

You can refer all CSS selectors [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/).

In this case `#parent > .one` will search for elements with class `one` which are immediate children of element with id `parent`.

```js
var count = document.querySelectorAll("#parent > .one").length;
console.log(count);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```